# designing a horizontal checkbox

Tags: html, checkbox

I intend to design a multiple choice question using an HTML file in a way that the choices appear horizontally. Here is what I have tried:

```
<checkbox-answer
    options = question.tokens
    answer2 = "question.answer"
>
</checkbox-answer>
```

Tokens refer to the choices that have to appear. However, they appear vertically like this:

```
choice 1
choice 2
choice 3
```

How can I modify it so that they appear horizontally like this?:

```
choice 1    choice 2    choice 3
```

Comment: The code sample you quote in your question is not HTML. What language/framework/tool are you working with?

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```css
        .dbgOuter{
            border: solid 1px #888;
            border-radius: 4px;
            padding: 3px 8px 0px 14px;
            width: 340px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            font-size: 10.5pt;
        }
        .dbgCont{
            display: inline-block;
            height: 24px;
            margin-left: 6px;
        }
        /* Base for label styling */
        .dbgCheck:not(:checked),
        .dbgCheck:checked {
            position: absolute;
            left: -9999px;
        }
        .dbgCheck:not(:checked) + label,
        .dbgCheck:checked + label {
            display:inline-block;
            position: relative;
            padding-left: 25px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        /* checkbox aspect */
        .dbgCheck:not(:checked) + label:before,
        .dbgCheck:checked + label:before {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            left:0; top: 1px;
            width: 17px; height: 17px;
            border: 1px solid #aaa;
            background: #f8f8f8;
            border-radius: 3px;
            box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px   rgba(0,0,0,.3)
        }
        /* checkmark aspect */
        .dbgCheck:not(:checked) + label:after,
        .dbgCheck:checked + label:after {
            content: '✔';
            position: absolute;
            top: 2px; left: 5px;
            font-size: 14px;
            color: #09ad7e;
            transition: all .2s;
        }
        /* checked mark aspect changes */
        .dbgCheck:not(:checked) + label:after {
            opacity: 0;
            transform: scale(0);
        }
        .dbgCheck:checked + label:after {
            opacity: 1;
            transform: scale(1);
        }
        /* disabled checkbox */
        .dbgCheck:disabled:not(:checked) + label:before,
        .dbgCheck:disabled:checked + label:before {
            box-shadow: none;
            border-color: #bbb;
            background-color: #ddd;
        }
        .dbgCheck:disabled:checked + label:after {
            color: #999;
        }
        .dbgCheck:disabled + label {
            color: #aaa;
        }
        /* accessibility */
        .dbgCheck:checked:focus + label:before,
        .dbgCheck:not(:checked):focus + label:before {
            border: 1px dotted blue;
        }

        .dbgCheck{
            display:inline-block;
            width:90px;
            height:24px;
            margin:1em;
        }





        /* Useless styles, just for demo design */

        body {
            font-family: "Open sans", "Segoe UI", "Segoe WP", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            color: #666;
        }
        h1, h2 {
            margin-bottom: 5px;
            font-weight: normal;
            text-align: center;
        }
        h2 {
            margin: 5px 0 2em;
            color: #aaa;
        }
        form {
            width: 80px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        .txtcenter {
            margin-top: 4em;
            font-size: .9em;
            text-align: center;
            color: #aaa;
        }
        .copy {
            margin-top: 2em;
        }
        .copy a {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #4778d9;
        }
```

```html
<h2>horizontal checkboxes</h2>
   <div class="dbgOuter">
    <div class="dbgCont">
        <input type="checkbox" id="dbgTrace" class="dbgCheck" />
        <label for="dbgTrace">choice 1</label>
    </div>
    <div class="dbgCont">
        <input type="checkbox" id="dbgDebug" class="dbgCheck" />
        <label for="dbgDebug">choice 2</label>
    </div>
    <div class="dbgCont">
        <input type="checkbox" id="dbgInfo" class="dbgCheck" checked="checked" />
        <label for="dbgInfo">choice 3</label>
    </div>
    
   </div>
<p class="txtcenter">Custom styles on modern browsers.<br/>Classical checkboxes on IE8 and lower.</p>
```

Comment: I can't give my choices manually as in here because they are read from a different file and their number is not predetermined. They are written in "options".